# uncaught typeerror INCLUDES is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First click on item console log item inside arr. Second click returns error uncaught type error includes is not a function. And console log arr is 1.

Chrome browser

```
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state = {
  arr = []
}
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick(e) {
  let arr = this.state.arr
  let item = e.target.id
  if (!arr.includes(item)) {
    this.setState({arr: arr.push(item)})
  } else {
    this.setState({arr: arr.filter(x => x !== item)})
  }
}
```

Comment: `item.push(item)` ?? *edit* also just noticed that the object literal that initializes `this.state` is also a syntax error.

Comment: The browser is?

Comment: Add debugging.... make sure arr is what you think it is....

Comment: Also note that `.filter()` returns a new array; it does not modify the original array. You'll have to reassign the result of that call back to `this.state.arr`.

Comment: Be careful of using `this` in functions it may not be what you expect it to be.

Comment: How are you binding the click handler?

Comment: @epascarello It's like this thing that lets you go on teh intarwabs. Arr is what pirates say.

Comment: Maybe I am mutating state?

Comment: So something is setting the state to something else. Impossible to tell from what you provided.

Comment: @Benz Of course you are: you push directly onto the array *and* you don't call `setState`.

Comment: what happens if you do `if (arr && !arr.includes(item)) ...`

Comment: Sorry @DaveNewton that was a typo on my end. I fixed the typo. That was my original code. But it works it with ......this.setState({arr: [...this.state.arr, item]})

Comment: You keep changing the code.... is it what you actually have, or what you are trying!!!!!!!

Comment: `this.setState({arr: arr.push(item)})` is WRONG because you are setting what push  returns.....

Comment: Sorry. First time asking here. Did not post code properly. This is definitely the code I had.

Answer (score 1):

react says that data is inmutable, also your handle click by far as I see is not binded, thus do this

```
handleClick = (e)=> {
  let arr = this.state.arr
}
```

then make a copy of state

```
handleClick = (e)=> {
  let arr = Object.assign([],this.state.arr)
}
```

and at the end set state of data

```
handleClick = (e)=> {
  .....
  this.setState({arr: newArr})
 //{arr: arr}
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @D3Portillo. I was definitely mutating state when I was not suppose to.

Comment: np bro ;3 , a pleasure